Need help solving Interview Question: Reverse FizzBuzz
I recently gave an interview for a company and was asked this coding question:
FizzBuzz is a classic childrens game that has made it's way into coding for fun. The problem can be described with following rules:

for the given integers f, b and n, write a program that prints the numbers 1 to n
for multiples of f print "Fizz"
for multiples of b print "Buzz"
for multiples of f and b print "FizzBuzz"
for other cases print the number

So... what is reverse FizzBuzz?
We have n values of FizzBuzz output, but we do not know the f and b values. Using the FizzBuzz output as the input to our program, find original f and b values (so called "Multiplier Values").
For example, if the input is ("1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz") then the output should be 3 5
code
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FizzBuzzMultiplierFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] fizzBuzzOutput = {"1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz"};
        findFizzBuzzMultipliers(fizzBuzzOutput);
    }

    public static void findFizzBuzzMultipliers(String[] fizzBuzzOutput) {
        List<Integer> fizzPositions = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> buzzPositions = new ArrayList<>();

        // Find positions of "Fizz" and "Buzz" in the output
        for (int i = 0; i < fizzBuzzOutput.length; i++) {
            if (fizzBuzzOutput[i].contains("Fizz")) {
                fizzPositions.add(i + 1); // +1 to convert index to position
            }
            if (fizzBuzzOutput[i].contains("Buzz")) {
                buzzPositions.add(i + 1); // +1 to convert index to position
            }
        }

        // Determine the smallest multiple for Fizz (f)
        int f = findGCD(fizzPositions);

        // Determine the smallest multiple for Buzz (b)
        int b = findGCD(buzzPositions);

        System.out.println("f = " + f + ", b = " + b);
    }

    // Helper method to find the Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)
    public static int findGCD(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int gcd = numbers.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            gcd = gcd(gcd, numbers.get(i));
        }
        return gcd;
    }

    // Helper method to calculate GCD of two numbers
    public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (b == 0) {
            return a;
        }
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
}

I was able to solve the question finding the greatest common denominator between f and b.
Later the interviewer told me that this code would not work for this input:
String[] input5 = { "Fizz", "Buzz", "52", "53", "54", "Fizz", "56", "57", "58", "59", "Fizz", "61", "62", "63", "64", "Fizz", "66", "67", "68", "69", "Fizz" }

Expected output is 5, 51.
Need help refactoring my code to satisfy the above test case
Tried reading the String array and updating the indexes based on the numbers in the array. The code becomes too messy and unable to find an optimized solution

by the way, the posted last input is not exactly the reverse of FizzBuzz ... "prints the numbers 1 to n"

In this case what you could do is get the offset/distance between two Fizz/Buzz and that would be you Fizz/Buzz number. In case there is only one Fizz/Buzz then the Fizz/Buzz number is just the position where it is, which you can calculate by getting the first number in the list then offsetting it by the position of Fizz/Buzz index.
Here is a pseudo code for it (the code assumes that the input has only one valid Fizz and Buzz values and that there is at least one number in the input):
fizzBuzzOutput = { "Fizz", "Buzz", "52", "53", "54", "Fizz", "56", ... }

// same as you did, just dont add +1 to i
fizzPositions = { 0, 5, ... }
buzzPositions = { 1 }

// get the index of the first parsable int
// you could do this with a for loop and try and parse
firstNumberIndex = 2

if (fizzPositions.length > 1) {
    fizz = fizzPositions[1] - fizzPositions[0] // that would 5
} else {
    fizz = fizzBuzzOutput[firstNumberIndex] + (fizzPositions[0] - firstNumberIndex)
}

if (buzzPositions.length > 1) {
    buzz = buzzPositions[1] - buzzPositions[0]
} else {
    // 52 + (1 - 2)
    buzz = fizzBuzzOutput[firstNumberIndex] + (buzzPositions[0] - firstNumberIndex)
}

// you don't need the gcd methods


It's more complicated than this. If the input ended at 56, then buzz could be either 51 or 17. But your algorithm would only say it's 51. With the given input, we know it can't be 17 because the input has "68" in place of "buzz".

yeah there could be more possibilities for fizz and buzz, but in my answer I assumed that the input has only one valid fizz and buzz value

Your code doesn't work for the alternative dataset because you assume the first number in the list is always 1, so you can simply get the index in the list and add 1 to get the number. But in this case, it's not 1, but rather 50, which 1. means the index is not equal to number-1, and 2. means that the first number immediately triggers a fizz.
The easiest solution is probably to make the offset you use relative to the index dynamic. I will not tell you how to do that because that would be solving the interview question for you.

I will start from two assumptions, the first one, which I think we all take for granted is that “1” is not a valid answer, the second one is that the highest of the values found (in case there are several) should be returned, this assumption is based on the fact that the last example presented, admits as valid answers “5, 3” also “5, 17” and “5, 51”, then, given that the interviewer takes for good the result “5, 51”, I think it is a good assumption.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FizzBuzzMultiplierFinder {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      FizzBuzzMultiplierFinder fbmf = new FizzBuzzMultiplierFinder();
      String fizzBuzzOutput[] = { "1", "2", "Fizz", "4", "Buzz", "Fizz", "7", "8", "Fizz", "Buzz", "11", "Fizz", "13", "14", "FizzBuzz" };
      fbmf.findFizzBuzzMultipliers( fizzBuzzOutput );
   }

   public void findFizzBuzzMultipliers( String[] fizzBuzzOutput ) {
      int ini = 0;

        // in this step, we identify the numerical value of the first item in the list
      for( int i = 0; i < fizzBuzzOutput.length; i ++ ) {
         if( fizzBuzzOutput[ i ].matches( "[0-9]" ) ) {
            ini = Integer.parseInt( fizzBuzzOutput[ i ] ) - i;
            break;
         }
      }
      System.out.println( getResult( fizzBuzzOutput, ini, "Fizz" ) + " " + getResult( fizzBuzzOutput, ini, "Buzz" ) );
   }

     // this method invokes "subMultiples" which creates a list of lists of submultiples, 
     // and returns the value returned by "getNumber", to which it passes as argument, 
     // the obtained list.
   int getResult( String input5[], int ini, String type ) {
      List<List<Integer>> lis = new ArrayList<>();
      for( int i = 0, k = ini; i < input5.length; i ++, k ++ ) {
         if( input5[ i ].equals( type )
                 || input5[ i ].equals( "FizzBuzz" ) ) {
            lis.add( subMultiples( k ) );
         }
      }
      return getNumber( lis );
   }

     // return a list of submultiples
   List<Integer> subMultiples( int number ) {
      List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<>();
      for( int i = number; i > 1; i -- ) {
         if( number % i == 0 ) {
            out.add( i );
         }
      }
      return out;
   }

     // this method generates the candidates and verifies by calling “isInList”
     // if it is valid, if so, it returns it. 
   int getNumber( List<List<Integer>> lis ) {
      int number;
      for( int i = 0; i < lis.size(); i ++ ) {
         List<Integer> l = lis.get( i );
         for( int k = 0; k < l.size(); k ++ ) {
            number = l.get( k );
            if( isInList( lis, number ) ) {
               return number;
            }
         }
      }
      return -1;
   }

     // return "true" if the number is contained in all lists
   boolean isInList( List<List<Integer>> lis, int number ) {
      for( int i = 0; i < lis.size(); i ++ ) {
         int amount = lis.get( i ).size();
         for( int k = 0; k < lis.get( i ).size(); k ++ ) {
            if( lis.get( i ).get( k ) == number ) {
               break;
            }
            if( k == amount - 1 ) {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }
      return true;
   }    
}

